# How to transfer props to children's children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm transferring some props from a layout to every children. This works when the child is a direct layout's children, but it doesn't work when I wrap a layout's child in a, for example, div.

**Working case:**

```
<Layout >
  <SectionA  language={props.language}  />
</Layout>
```

**But it doesn't in this case:**

```
<Layout >
   <div>
     <SectionA  language={props.language}  />
   </div>
</Layout>
```

**When I access to props.language in `<SectionA />` component, it's undefined*

Here's how I'm transferring the props from the layout to its children

```
render(){

   const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            language: this.state.language,
        });
    });


 return (
        {children}
 )
    }
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you're trying to add a prop to Layout's child which in your second example is the div element, NOT the Section component.

Comment: I'm trying to add a prop to SectionA component, which is inside of a div in the second example. I'm wrapping SectionA with a div for styling purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a pretty good case for the [useContext hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext). This would allow you to pass language down as context to all children of the context provider. For example:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const LanguageContext = createContext();

const LanguageProvider = (props) => {
    // Can set up state here if needed
    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider value={'defaultLanguage'}>
            {props.children}
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
};

// Wrap the components that need access to the context in the provider
const App = () => {
    return (
        <LanguageProvider>
            <Layout>
                <div>
                    <SectionA />
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </LanguageProvider>
    );
};


// And to access that context in SectionA (or any other child)
const SectionA = () => {
    const language = useContext(LanguageContext);

    return (<h1>Language is {language}</h1>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this (probably in the layout file), but here is how I solved this problem:

First I used a second hoc to wrap and style the sectionA component:

```
function simpleWrapper(props) {


return(
    <React.Fragment>
    <div className='container'>
      <SectionA language={props.language}/>  
    </div>
    <div>
      <SectionB language={props.language}/>  
    </div>
     ...
    <style jsx>{`
      .container {
        Stuff
    `}</style>
    </React.Fragment>
)
}

export default simpleWrapper;
```

And then I transferred all props to this wrapper:

```
<Layout >
  <SimpleWrapper language={props.language} />

</Layout>
```

)

Note that I'm using this approach because I have more than only 1 component inside of